# Migrating an enterprise app from Angular 1.5 to React

Tags: angularjs, reactjs

I have an enterprise application, written in Angular 1.5. I want to migrate to React. The application has multiple parts, and cannot be done (too risky) in one shot. So I plan on migrating component by component. It means that in the intermediatory state, the application will be partially in Angular and partially in React. For example, as a first step, the header can be converted into a React component, and so on. Could you please provide if there are any best practices for this migration. Or what should be the ideal migration path? Appreciate your answers.

Comment: Sorry, your question makes no sense to me. I understand the risk you mention, but that's what a dev/testing stage is for. Can't you just rewrite the entire application in React and push it to production once it's thoroughly tested and behaves consistently? What's the point of going to production with a half-angular half-react application?

Comment: The existing application is constantly getting updated. So with limited resources we have to handle both migration, and creation of new features. Doing the entire app in one shot is not feasible.

Comment: @Dan That is what git is for. Just create a new branch, work on it in your spare time, and to fix features, change branches. Then you only publish the angular branch, till everything is ok in the other branch and you publish it as a new and (maybe) better version.